# Flutter in_app_purchase refunds

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase

I'm looking for the best practises for in_app_purchase for nonconsumables. As far as I can see the example does not handle refunds but looks like if I call restorePurchases() when my app starts I can work out what the user has purchased. Is this the correct way to handle refunds?

Comment: hey @david-broadhurst, were you able to find a solution for this? Also facing same problem